# uploading image to image folder with unique name

Tags: php

This is my image uploading page. what i want is lil bit edition. I want image name look like (folder) image/userid_time.jpg

so i want to upload image to image folder,

and i want all image have new name or we can say unique name.

any adition in this please.

```
<?php // upload2.php
echo <<<_END
<html><head><title>PHP Form Upload</title></head><body>
<form method='post' action='upload2.php' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
Select a JPG, GIF, PNG or TIF File:
<input type='file' name='filename' size='10' />
<input type='submit' value='Upload' /></form>
_END;
if ($_FILES) {
    $name = $_FILES['filename']['name'];
    switch ($_FILES['filename']['type']) {
        case 'image/jpeg':
            $ext = 'jpg';
            break;
        case 'image/gif':
            $ext = 'gif';
            break;
        case 'image/png':
            $ext = 'png';
            break;
        case 'image/tiff':
            $ext = 'tif';
            break;
        default:
            $ext = '';
            break;
    }
    if ($ext) {
        $n = "image.$ext";
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], $n);
        echo "Uploaded image '$name' as '$n':<br />";
        echo "<img src='$n' />";
    } else
        echo "'$name' is not an accepted image file";
} else
    echo "No image has been uploaded";
echo "</body></html>";
?>
```

**Thanks :)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can get the user id into a variable called $userId, you can change the $n variable as was previously suggested.

```
$timestamp = time();
$n = "image/$userId_$timestamp.$ext";
```

When you execute the move_uploaded_file() method, the file will be moved into the image directory **relative to the location of your upload script**.  You might want to make sure that the image folder already exists, and is writable.

Answer (score 1):

You can have the file name and then you can append it with `uniqid("{$filename}_")`. So the output would be something like `filename_4b3403665fea6` and then you can add the extension :)

Docs here: http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

EDIT: I apologise, I mis-read your question.

Answer (score 1):

Just change `$n`. Since you're always setting it to `"image.$ext"` you will always get the same filename.

Instead, you will need to name it how you want it. Something like `$userid."_".time().".".$ext`, assuming the user's ID is in `$userid`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/about/) because:

- Multiple File Uploads
- Drag and Drop
- Real-Time Progress Indicators
- Custom Upload Restrictions
- Extreme Customization

and ...

```
...$verifyToken = md5('unique_salt' . $_POST['timestamp']);...
```

see [demo](http://www.uploadify.com/demos/)

Comment: i tried on localhost. i have no clue where all file getting uploaded. and what is database setting?